# russian letters inside javascript script transform into diamonds

Tags: javascript

I create items on the page like this

```
    var list_item = "";
    if (eventstatus == 'CANCELED') {
         list_item = '<li class="media list-group-item list-group-item-info"  id="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Event canceled! Impossible to enroll!">';
         tooltipflag = true;
    }
    else list_item = '<li class="media list-group-item list-group-item-info">';
    list_item += '<a class="pull-left" href="#">';
    list_item += '<img class="media-object img-thumbnail" src="holder.js/200x120" alt="NO IMAGE">';
    list_item += "</a>";
    list_item += '<div class="media-body">';
    list_item += '<h4 class="media-heading">';
    if (eventstatus == 'CANCELED') list_item += name + ' <span class="label label-danger">' + eventstatus + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span></span>';
    else if (eventstatus == 'DRAFT') list_item += name + ' <span class="label label-warning">' + 'SOON' + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>';
    else list_item += name + ' <span class="label label-primary">' + 'NEW' + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span></span>';
    list_item += '</h4>';
    list_item += '<p>' + description + '</p>';
    list_item += '<br>';
    list_item += '<div class="form-group pull-right">';
    list_item += '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" id="info_button' + i + '" data-target="#info' + i + '" >';
    list_item += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Просмотреть информацию';
    list_item += '</button>';
    if (eventstatus == 'CANCELED') list_item += '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm disabled" data-toggle="modal" id="enroll" data-target="#enroll">';
    else list_item += '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enroll">';
    list_item += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Записаться';
    list_item += '</button>';
    list_item += '</div></div></li>';
    return list_item;
```

But words `Просмотреть информацию` & `Записаться` look like [image]

But if I write it in `html` code - not in javascript function - it looks properly.

What is wrong?

Comment: The fundamental issue here is encoding. Make sure the script is encoded in the format you expect (UTF-8 is probably your best option), and serve it with the correct `charset` on the mime type (e.g., `ContentType: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8`). Your life will be a LOT easier if you also do that with the HTML, and if you use the same encoding for the HTML and script.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your file is properly encoded in UTF-8 and served as UTF-8 (check the settings of your http server if necessary), you can declare the script in UTF-8 in the import like this :

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="yourFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hm...It doesn't work. But when I copy js code to my page - russian letters are shown properly. When I load it from js file - they don't.

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser's developer tools : look at the headers of the js file answer, is it served as UTF-8 or not ? If not, look at the http server settings (what server are you using ?).

Comment: Where? In Mozilla it shows response as `server : Apache Coyote 1.1` and `host etag` response headers. I'm  using tomcat.

Comment: What version of Tomcat do you have? I think I remember Tomcat6 had problems with UTF-8.

Comment: I'm using tomcat7....Well actually in console it starts `tomcat servlet engine 6`